# Make Multiple High-scores for Different Difficulties

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am very new to unity and I'm making a snake game. The snake game has different levels of difficulty, I would like to make a high score for each of them(I have 4) such as Easy Highscore and Hard Highscore Here is my code for the current high score.
This is not my whole code but the snippets with the high score in them.

```
        int highScore;

        highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Highscore", 0);

        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Highscore") <= highScore) {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Highscore", highScore);
        }

    public void highscoreFun()
    {
        highScoreText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Highscore").ToString();
        gameOverHighScoreText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Highscore").ToString();
    }

                    currentScore++;
                    if(currentScore >= highScore)
                    {
                        highScore = currentScore;
                    }
```

And here is my code for the difficulty.

```
 public void PlayGame()
{

    DifficultyToggles.transform.GetChild((int)GameManager.Difficulty).GetComponent<Toggle>().isOn = true;
}

#region Difficulty
public void SetEasyDifficulty(bool isOn)
{
    if (isOn)
        GameManager.Difficulty = GameManager.Difficulties.Easy;
}

public void SetIntermediateDifficulty(bool isOn)
{
    if (isOn)
        GameManager.Difficulty = GameManager.Difficulties.Intermediate;
}

public void SetHardDifficulty(bool isOn)
{
    if (isOn)
        GameManager.Difficulty = GameManager.Difficulties.Hard;
}

public void SetImposibleDifficulty(bool isOn)
{
    if (isOn)
        GameManager.Difficulty = GameManager.Difficulties.Imposible;
}
#endregion
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please tell me the problem so I can help you? Thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry, thanks for pointing that out! I'm trying to get different high scores for different difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an if-statement asserting if the difficulty is easy, normal, hard etc..
This code below cover for all difficulties, since GameManager.Difficulty just has to be true.

```
`
 public void SetEasyDifficulty(bool isOn)
 {
   if (isOn)
     GameManager.Difficulty = GameManager.Difficulties.Easy;
    
   if(GameManager.Difficulty)
      highscoreFun();
     
  }
```

/* I don't know if it is going to work for your design in particular. Let me know if it
works.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out!

Answer (score 0):

You are only creating one high score value in your player prefs. Maybe consider checking the difficulty of the game when adding to the score and creating a new player prefs int for each high score difficulty.